# cakephp and XE Currency converter?

Tags: cakephp, iframe, converters, currency

I would like to have the XE Currency converter integrated in my website, but would like to have the output on my website same page and not being redirected to the XE website, how to realise this?  with iframe? Please could you provide me with an example? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

you can actually submit query to xe.com and parse the data from it using curl

```
    <?php


    $url = "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=PHP";

    $ch = curl_init(); // Initialize a CURL session.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Return Page contents.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // Pass URL as parameter.

    $data = curl_exec($ch); // grab URL and pass it to the variable.
    curl_close($ch); // close curl resource, and free up system resources.


    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $tableRows = $xpath->query('//table//tr');

    $details = array();

    foreach ($tableRows as $row) {
            // fetch all 'tds' inside this 'tr'
            $td = $xpath->query('td', $row);

            if ($td->length == 3  ):

                foreach($td as $key => $val){

                    if($key==0 Or $key ==2) {

                        $details[] = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9, \'\.:]*/i', '',$val->nodeValue);


                    }

                }


            endif;
    }

     print "<pre>";
     print_r($details);
     print "</pre>";

    ?>
```

visit: http://myphptroubles.blogspot.com/2013/09/convert-currency-using-xecom-via-curl.html

Answer (score 0):

You can order a data feed from their page, it looks like:
http://www.xe.com/datafeed/

With that you can retrieve the currencies via PHP/curl etc and work with it just as normal data.

Comment: I am still a newbie in programming, do you have any example? That would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, a feed cost $540, forget that part :-)

Comment: I just use this: https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Lib/CurrencyLib.php

Comment: Thanks Mark, being a novice, would you mind to give a little instructions? I suppose I put this file in the /vendors folder? Do you have a small example in how to use it?